# Python - Custom ordering of elements within a dictionary

Tags: python, json, sorting, dictionary

I have an empty dictionary that will be used to represent a collection of timestamp data for position, velocity, etc. in order to store this information in a .json file. I wish to populate the dictionary in a given order so as to have all the position vector data (X-Y-Z values) together, all of the velocity vector data (X-Y-Z values) together, etc. My script for doing so looks like this:

```
dictEntries = {'timestamp':[]}
for entry in entries:
   ...
   posXYZ = entry.getPosXYZ()
   velXYZ = entry.getVelXYZ()
   eVctr = entry.getEulerAngle()
   posABC = entry.getPosABC()
   velABC = entry.getVelABC()

   tmStmp = {}

   tmStmp['zVel'] = velABC[2]
   tmStmp['yVel'] = velABC[1]
   tmStmp['xVel'] = velABC[0]

   tmStmp['zPos'] = posABC[2]
   tmStmp['yPos'] = posABC[1]
   tmStmp['xPos'] = posABC[0]

   tmStmp['Value'] = time
   ...
   dictEntries['timestamp'].append(tmStmp)
```

However, when I examine the output in the dictionary, the elements are ordered Alphabetically and based on capitalization (which is standard). The output to the .json file, printed using `json.dump()`, is unorganized related to how it was put into the dictionary

```
{
    "timestamp": [
       {
          "xPos": 5.2, 
          "zPos": 3.5,
          "yPos": 7.7,
          "Value": 0.0,
          "zVel": 3.5, 
          "xVel": 5.2,
          "yVel": 7.7
       }, 
       {...}
    ]
}
```

It's possible that the problem is caused by using `json.dump`, but I want to examine all possibilities before attempting a fix. Is there a way to sort the dictionary in a custom way in order to put position values together, velocities values together, etc.? Or is there a way to output the dictionary to the json file in a specific order rather than just dumping the contents into it?

Comment: use OrderedDict if you want entry order to be preserved.

Comment: `json.dump` accepts a boolean `sort_keys` argument: `json.dump(myDict, sort_keys=True)` will output your dictionary with keys in alphabetical order.

Comment: @karakfa OrderedDict seems like the perfect solution. Got it working as intended now.